# Multiple filters in Google chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is is possible to put multiple filters in the network filter input. An example use case would be having something like
Domain:cycle.com OR domain:cuz.com. I would only like to see network requests from both those domains and nothing else. I did a lot of searching but have not found a solution.

Comment: Workaround: `/(cycle|cuz)\.com\//`

Comment: This works perfectly and I was able to do some other great filters too using this, thank you

Answer (score 9):

As per the Google Chrome Developer docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter-by-property), we can see that:

> You can use multiple properties simultaneously by separating each property with a space. For example, `mime-type:image/gif larger-than:1K` displays all GIFs that are larger than one kilobyte. These multi-property filters are equivalent to AND operations. OR operations are currently not supported.